# Math not working in curve with out and in angle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am facing a strange error. I am using pgf/tikz 3.0.1 cvs to plot a curve with in and out angles. I am using mathematical calculations to obtain the second coordinate. Strangely, when I use a trigonometric function in the x coordinate I get an error but the same expression works in the y coordinate. I am pasting the code below

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,positioning,calc,decorations.markings}
    \usepackage{float}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {$xs$}; % initial point
        \node at (11.5,2) {$xg$}; % final point
        %\draw (0:0.375) to[out=0,in=210] ({11.5+0.375*cos(210)},{2+0.375*sin(210)}); 
                %Does not work
                \draw (0:0.375) to[out=0,in=210] ({11.5+0.375*0.5},{2+0.375*sin(210)});
                % Works fine
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{title}
    \label{fig:trajs}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me out here.

Comment: I don't know why but a second pair of braces solved the problem: `({{11.5+0.375*cos(210)}},...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of `\pgfmathsetmacro`  to define your coordinates.

```
\documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,positioning,calc,decorations.markings}
    \usepackage{float}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\xcor{11.5+0.375*cos(210)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ycor{2+0.375*sin(210)}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (0,0) {$xs$}; % initial point
        \node at (11.5,2) {$xg$}; % final point
        \draw (0:0.375) to[out=0,in=210] (\xcor,\ycor); 
        \draw (0:0.375) to[out=0,in=210] ({11.5+0.375*0.5},{2+0.375*sin(210)});
                % Works fine
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{title}
    \label{fig:trajs}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```